# Google Map showing on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am developing an app which uses Google Map. Everything is OK on emulator and the map works and shows the markers. But on real device it seems the fragment is not exist at all, there is no black screen or exception!

I know about the debug and release API keys and i am sure there is nothing wrong in this part. Both debug and release version of the app tested on real device but results were the same.

The following images are from the emulator and real device. Any advice would be helpful.

[image: Emulator]
[image: Device]

Comment: create an apk package and install it on the device, the map should show up.

Comment: The image in right is the running app on real device! and the map did not show up.

Comment: are you using the device while connected to your development application or you installed an apk file.

Answer (score 1):

It's wired, you can try to `change devices` to have a another try. Mark sure you put the `map fragment` in XML something like following:

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

And initial map as follows:

```
// Initial Map
        try {

            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also, you can the source code on my Github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android). It includes a working `map fragment on the real device`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was opengl es version. It was smaller than 2!